# How do you run a function when any data in an object is changed using Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js, vuejs2

So I have the following data, and my goal is to recalculate the user's results every time data in this object is changed. Here is the data.

```
data() {
  return {     
    test: 0, 
    userData: {
      sex: null,
      age: null,
      feet: null,
      inches: null,
      activity: null,
      goal: null,
    },
  }
}
```

Now I have tried to implement both watch and computed, but it seams Vue is not noticing when individual items in the object are changed. However, if I take some data out of the object it does notice the change.

Here is what I tried for watch:

```
watch: {
  userData: function () {
    console.log("Changed");
  }
}
```

The result was nothing in the console.

For computed I tried the following:

```
computed: {
  results: function () {
    console.log(this.userData);
    return this.userData.sex;
  }
}
```

But again nothing was printed in the console.

If I tried with the test variable:

```
watch: {
  test: function () {
    console.log("Changed");
  }
}
```

It WOULD output changed when the variable was changed. So that works because it is not an object.

Any help would be very appreciated. Again the goal is to recalculate results whenever any userData is changed.

Comment: You might want to use `Vue.set` and `Vue.delete` as Vue doesn't have reactivity for nested objects: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set

Comment: @match How can I run a function on change with this approach though?

Comment: Just make sure that whatever changes the object uses  `Vue.set` (rather than direct object manipulation - this will let Vue 'notice' it has changed, and your `watch` function will then be fired.

Comment: @match So for sex I could use something like this? `Vue.set( userData, sex, male )`. And would the same watcher now work?

Comment: Yes - that should allow Vue to 'see' the change. You might also want to look into Vuex as a better way of dealing with state changes.

Comment: @match thank you so much, now how would I update the object in an input where I previously had `<md-input v-model="userData.age" type="number"></md-input>'? Do I just replace the userData.age, or do I need an onchange function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you actually using the `results` property (in your template for example)? Computed properties do not get recomputed if they are not being used.

As opposed to what @match says, I doubt you have a reactivity problem since you do not add or delete properties (they already exist in your data so they are already reactive).

Comment: I wasn't, let me give it a shot!

Comment: This worked, the computed I wrote was working but I didn't have the results in the page so it wasn't running!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it. You need (as @match mentioned) use `Vue.set()` or `vm.$set()`. I found it was also necessary to update your watcher property to `userData.sex`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {  
    status: '', 
    userData: {
      sex: ''
    },
  },
  methods: {
    updateValues(){
      // Or Vue.set()
      this.$nextTick( function(){
        const newUserData = Object.assign({}, this.userData);
        newUserData.sex = "Male";
        this.userData = newUserData;
      });
    }
  },
  watch: {
    userData: function (v) {
      this.status += "userData Changed";
    },
    'userData.sex': function (v) {
      this.status += "\nuserData.sex Changed";
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.8/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <pre v-text="'userData.sex = ' + userData.sex"></pre>
  <pre v-text="status"></pre>
  <button @click="updateValues()">
    Change Sex
  </button>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Re-assigning the whole object, `userData`, triggers the `watch.userData`.

Comment: would this detect a change if I watched userData? I want to run one function for any change of the userData.

Comment: @AnthonySette I have updated the code to make this work, requires re-assigning the whole `userData` object.